# How to just copy files with wix toolset, no product no update, no uninstall

Tags: wix, wix3

This is a general question: we have an MSI with features created with WIX. We just have to provide the files to the customer related to the selected features, but without any installation or information on the “add and remove programs” and any uninstall just giving out the files. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to suppress the PublishComponents, PublishFeature and PublishProduct actions in the InstallExecuteSequence.

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
 <PublishComponents Suppress="Yes" />
 <PublishFeatures Suppress="Yes" />
 <PublishProduct Suppress="Yes" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: thank you this works ! 
Bonus questions : is there a way to get a NEW MSI from the given MSI based on the user Feature selection that can be than executed without feature selection. So e.g. a admin select all features, press ok and the result is a new MSI (including all custom execs) which the end user can run ?

Comment: Not technically a new MSI but google the concept administrative installations.  Normally for this kind of behavior you would create a transform for the MSI or command line installation  msiexec /i foo.msi ADDLOCAL=FEATUREA,FEATUREB,FEATUREC

Comment: But if the admin is selecting all features, what do you expect to be different about it?

Comment: sorry for the late reply .. the admin/projectmanager should prepare a "smaller" MSI for the user because there are so many features.